# Sum of values within yearly quarters

Tags: mysql, date

I currently have an SQL query that grabs customers' sales data and sums it up by month and year.  What I want to do is aggregate this data by quarter.  The current query is as follows.

```
SELECT A.*, DATE_FORMAT(C.TxnDate, '%Y-%m') AS FormattedTxnDate, SUM(C.Quantity * D.TotalCost) AS COGS, SUM(C.Quantity * C.Amount) AS Revenue
FROM customer_info A, invoices B, invoice_lines C, inventory D
WHERE A.CustomerID = B.CustomerID 
AND   B.TxnID = C.TxnID
AND   C.ItemID = D.ID
AND B.TxnDate BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2016-04-06'
GROUP BY A.CustomerID, YEAR(B.TxnDate), MONTH(B.TxnDate) ASC
```

I attempted to change the last line in the query to:

```
GROUP BY A.CustomerID, YEAR(B.TxnDate), QUARTER(B.TxnDate) ASC
```

This didn't work as intended.  Even though values within the same quarter are totaled, the resulting FormattedTxnDate uses the first month of a given quarter with sales information (because the customer in question may not have bought anything during the actual first month, like April of Q2, meaning the FTD's month would be May).  Is there any way to use DATE_FORMAT to show a quarter rather than the month?  I thought there might be a `%q` option but I was mistaken.  I should note that it's POSSIBLE to work with the formatted dates but it would probably be more tiresome and annoying than if I simply had them as quarters.

Answer (score 0):

Do two GROUP-BYs, one inside the other. This will give you the idea:

```
 select [list attributes of A], year, quarter, sum(revenue) as revenue from 
    (SELECT A.*, 
            DATE_FORMAT(C.TxnDate, '%Y-%m') AS FormattedTxnDate, 
            SUM(C.Quantity * D.TotalCost) AS COGS, 
            SUM(C.Quantity * C.Amount) AS Revenue,
            YEAR(B.TxnDate) as year,
            QUARTER(B.TxnDate) as quarter
     FROM customer_info A, invoices B, invoice_lines C, inventory D
       WHERE A.CustomerID = B.CustomerID 
        AND   B.TxnID = C.TxnID
        AND   C.ItemID = D.ID
        AND B.TxnDate BETWEEN '2013-04-01' AND '2016-04-06'
     GROUP BY A.CustomerID, YEAR(B.TxnDate), MONTH(B.TxnDate) ) as RIP
     GROUP BY [list all attributes of A], year, quarter
```

Personally I would do the GROUP-BYs first and then join with customer.

Another option is: do a subquery of B adding the quarter to your original query in the from section:

FROM ... , Invoices B, ...

to

```
   FROM ..., (select *, quarter(txndate) as quarter From Invoices) as B
```

then you can happily GROUP By year, quarter in your original query

Comment: I tried the second option.  It didn't work.  At first I tried simply inserting your last code example into the query in place of `invoices B` but I got the same results that I did before.  I then did a bit more modification by changing `B.TxnDate` to `B.Quarter` which caused the values themselves to get messed up.  I think it's now totaling everything within a given yearly period with that change.

Comment: did you replace the group by with: GROUP BY A.CustomerID, YEAR(B.TxnDate), quarter ASC

Comment: Tried that just now but FormattedTxnDate still doesn't give me the quarter.  It just shows the first available year and month of the quarter.